# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection even though I'm using the Reader properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, sqldatareader

I'm trying to figure out how to avoid this DataReader problem, for some reason in my code there's always some code running DataReader stuff and it keeps trying to do everything at once instead of waiting the readers to finish since I'm using the 'using' keyword, so, here is what I'm trying to do:

Controller method to change some Animal attributes

```
[HttpPost]        
    public ActionResult AlteraAnimal(Animal model)
    {
        Cliente _Cliente = new Cliente(AppUser.IdFirebase);
        Animal _Animal = new Animal();
        _Animal = model;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _Animal.idCliente = Cliente.IdCliente;
            int result = _Animal.Altera(_Animal);
            if (result > 0)
            {
                TempData["Resultado"] = result;
                TempData["Status"] = "AlteraçãoSucesso";
                _Cliente.CarregarDados(Cliente.IdFirebase);
            }


            ViewBag.Title = "Animais";
            return View("Animais", _Cliente);
        }

            TempData["Status"] = "Erro";
        
        ViewBag.Title = "Animais";
        return View("Animais",_Cliente);
    }
```

This is where the Exception occurs: ( System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.')

```
public int AlteraAgendamento(Agendamento _Agendamento)
    {
        try
        {
            int result = 0;
            if (ChecaDisponibilidade(_Agendamento.DataHoraInicio) == 1)
            {
                _Connection = Conectar();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("UPDATE Agendamento SET " +
                                            "IdAnimal=@IdAnimal, " +
                                            "DataHoraInicio=@DataHoraInicio, " +
                                            "DataHoraFim=@DataHoraFim " +
                         "WHERE IdAgendamento = @IdAgendamento ");

                String sql = sb.ToString();

                using (_Connection)
                {
                    using (SqlCommand _Command = new SqlCommand(sql, _Connection))
                    {
                        _Command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IdAnimal", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = _Agendamento.IdAnimal });
                        _Command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DataHoraInicio", SqlDbType.DateTime) { Value = _Agendamento.DataHoraInicio });
                        _Command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DataHoraFim", SqlDbType.DateTime) { Value = _Agendamento.DataHoraInicio.AddMinutes(30) });
                        _Command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IdAgendamento", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = _Agendamento.IdAgendamento });
                        result = _Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                AlteraAgendamentoServico(_Agendamento);
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                result = 2;
            } 
            
            _Agendamento.MsgStatus = "HorarioIndisponivel";
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        
    }
```

And for some reason this is where the Reader is located according to Visual Studio, but I thought that by using the 'using' keyword the readers would close themselves without any problem, maybe they are executing all at once, should I wait for them to finish using Readers before doing anything?

```
public string GetDescricaoTipoAnimal(int idRaca)
    {
        try
        {
            var _Table = new DataTable();
            _Connection = Conectar();



            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("SELECT " +
                                   "IdRaca, " +
                                   "IdTipoAnimal " +
                                   "FROM Raca " +
                                   "WHERE " +
                                   "IdRaca = " + "@IdRaca");

            String sql = sb.ToString();
            using (_Connection)
            {
                using (SqlCommand _Command = new SqlCommand(sql, _Connection))
                {
                    _Command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IdRaca", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = idRaca });
                    SqlDataReader reader;
                    using (reader = _Command.ExecuteReader()) //THIS IS THE READER CAUSING EXCEPTION
                    {
                        _Table.Load(reader);
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (DataRow _RowAnimais in _Table.Rows)
            {
                idTipoAnimal = Convert.ToInt32(_RowAnimais.ItemArray[1]);
            }

            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("SELECT " +
                                   "IdTipoAnimal, " +
                                   "Descricao " +
                                   "FROM TipoAnimal " +
                                   "WHERE " +
                                   "IdTipoAnimal = " + idTipoAnimal);

            sql = sb.ToString();
            _Table = new DataTable();
            _Connection = Conectar();
            using (_Connection)
            {
                using (SqlCommand _Command = new SqlCommand(sql, _Connection))
                {
                    SqlDataReader reader;
                    using (reader = _Command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        _Table.Load(reader);
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (DataRow _RowAnimais in _Table.Rows)
            {
                descricaoTipoAnimal = Convert.ToString(_RowAnimais.ItemArray[1]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw e;
        }
        return descricaoTipoAnimal;
    }
```

I'm also kinda new to StackOverflow so forgive me if this is not the best format, appreciate any kind of help, if anyone need more information please feel free to ask me and I will update my question.

Thanks!

--- EDIT ---

I'm using MultipleActiveResultSets=True; in my connection string

This is Conectar() method to grab the sql connection

```
public static SqlConnection Conectar()
    {
        if (_Conexao.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            try
            {                    
                if (ConnectionString != null && ConnectionString != string.Empty)
                {
                    _Conexao = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

                    _Conexao.Open();
                }
                else
                    throw new Exception("String de conexão inexistente");
            }
            catch (Exception _Ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Banco de Dados Indisponível. " + Environment.NewLine + _Ex.Message);
            }
        }

        return _Conexao;
    }
```

And this is the forms I post the data to the controller

```
<form asp-action="AlteraAnimal" asp-controller="Animais" method="post" id="formAlteracaoAnimal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select hidden asp-for="idAnimal" class="form-control" id="idAnimalSelectAlteracao">
                        <option value="@Model.idAnimal"></option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nomeAnimalInputAlteracao">Nome do animal</label>
                    <input asp-for="nome" type="text" class="form-control" id="nomeAnimalInputAlteracao" placeholder="Digite o nome do animal">
                    <span asp-validation-for="nome" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="SexoSelectAlteracao">Sexo</label>
                    <select asp-for="sexo" class="form-control" id="SexoSelectAlteracao">
                        <option value="1">Macho</option>
                        <option value="2">Fêmea</option>
                        <option value="3">Indefinido</option>
                    </select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="sexo" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="dataNascimentoSelectAlteracao">Data de nascimento:</label>
                    <input asp-for="dataNascimento" type="datetime-local" id="dataNascimentoSelectAlteracao">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="textCorAlteracao">Informe a cor do animal:</label>
                    <textarea asp-for="cor" class="form-control" id="textCorAlteracao" rows="1"></textarea>
                    <span asp-validation-for="cor" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="tipoAnimalAlteracao">Selecione o tipo de animal:</label>
                    <select asp-for="tipo" class="form-control" id="tipoAnimalAlteracao">
                        <option value="@Model.idTipoAnimal">@Model.descricaoTipoAnimal</option>
                        @foreach (TipoAnimal _TipoAnimal in Model.listaTipoAnimal)
                        {
                            if (Model.idTipoAnimal != _TipoAnimal.IdTipoAnimal)
                            {
                                <option value="@_TipoAnimal.IdTipoAnimal">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => _TipoAnimal.Descricao)</option>
                            }
                        }
                    </select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="tipo" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="racaAnimalAlteracao">Raça do animal</label>
                    <select asp-for="raca" class="form-control" id="racaAnimalAlteracao">
                        <option value="@Model.raca">@Model.raca</option>
                    </select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="raca" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select asp-for="idRaca" class="form-control" id="idRacaAnimalAlteracao" hidden>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="obsAdicionalAlteracao">Observações adicionais:</label>
                    <textarea asp-for="observacao" class="form-control" id="obsAdicionalAlteracao" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check-inline">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input asp-for="castrado" id="checkCastradoAlteracao" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">Castrado
                    </label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" hidden id="submitAlteracaoHidden"></button>
            </form>
```

Also, I figured out that you may need the ChecaDisponibilidade() code as well since it's called inside AlteraAgendamento()

```
public int ChecaDisponibilidade(DateTime DataInicio)
    {      
        if(DataInicio < DateTime.Now)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        try
        {
            int result = 0;
            int cont = 0;
            var _Table = new DataTable();
            _Connection = Conectar();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("SELECT " +
                                "IdAgendamento, " +
                                "Codigo, " +
                                "IdCliente, " +
                                "IdAnimal, " +
                                "DataCadastro, " +
                                "IdUsuarioCadastro, " +
                                "DataHoraInicio, " +
                                "DataHoraFim, " +
                                "Situacao, " +
                                "Observacao, " +
                                "Desabilitado, " +
                                "DataDesabilitado, " +
                                "IdUsuarioDesabilitado, " +
                                "IdOrdemServico " +
                        "FROM Agendamento " +
                        "WHERE DataHoraFim BETWEEN @DataInicio AND @DataFim " +
                                "OR DataHoraInicio BETWEEN @DataInicio AND @DataFim");
            String sql = sb.ToString();
            using (_Connection)
            {
                using (SqlCommand _Command = new SqlCommand(sql, _Connection))
                {
                    _Command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DataInicio", SqlDbType.DateTime) { Value = DataInicio });
                    _Command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DataFim", SqlDbType.DateTime) { Value = DataInicio.AddMinutes(30) });
                    SqlDataReader reader;
                    using (reader = _Command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        _Table.Load(reader);
                    }
                    cont = _Table.Rows.Count;

                    if (cont == 0)
                    {
                        //nao ha agendamentos no horario
                        result = 1;
                        return result;
                    }else
                    {
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why is `_Connection` a field and not a local variable? Where is your `Conectar()`code? You need that for a [mcve]. Why are you using StringBuilder to form your SQL when all you need is a single string literal? Why does `AlteraAgendamento` return an int? Why do you have a try/catch, where the only thing you do in the catch block is throw? And you're using `throw e;` which will lose the stack trace. If you need to rethrow a caught exception, just use `throw;` so the stack trace is preserved. Why do many of your local variable names start with an underscore?

Comment: Hi Mason, _Connection is a local variable which i grab the sql connection via Conectar(), I added the code to my question. AlteraAgendamento returning an int to represent if the result is valid or not, like a code. So I should change my throw e to just throw; ?
Also, the underscore means it is used locally only, it's a standard at my workplace

Comment: Actually _Connection is a field because I use it in most of my class methods

Comment: Well then, the error seems pretty clear. It's complaining that you have another reader opened on the same connection. If you're storing the connection as a field (which you should never do, it should almost always be a local variable) then it's a high likelihood that the connection is getting reused from other threads. To fix, don't make it a field. Wrap your connections in using statements so they're disposed of when you're finished with them.

Comment: Other recommendations: don't form your SQL strings via string cocatenations. You seem to know about using parameters, do just do `const string sql = @"your sql here";` which will even support line breaks. Don't use integers to represent success or failure of a method, that's what exceptions are for, or create distinct object or enum if failures are expected to regularly occur. Integers are just numbers, so they make a very poor result type. C# convention is _camelCase your field and camelCase your local variables. You're doing the opposite of this - probably should conform to the rest of world

Comment: Appreciate all the tips, I'm going to change my Connection to local variables instead of field and see if it solves the problem, thanks for your time explaining all this to me.